# How to identify invalid characters in a string of data in SQL Server Reportng Services and Visual Studio 2005

Tags: sql, service, reporting

I have a string of data in an output field in layout view, and want to check if any of the characters in the output are invalid. I have looked around your site for the last 2 hours and found some text I have bastardised to give me the right result but its very long winded :

I just need an iif statement with lots of "or's" in if, if the field has an "1" or and "3" or and"4" etc etc.

Nubie Tony K

Comment: Regexp or perhaps LIKE?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this in Reporting Services rather than in SQL?  Or are you talking about a query from SSRS?

Comment: I am using visual studio 2005 and querying an Oracle database.